# How to export model with my own customized functions using tensorflow-serving?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have a new requirement when using the [tensorflow-serving](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving) to export my model, what if I just only need to know the number on my input image rather than test this model with large test data? What should I do to achieve that or it's impossible to do that? Any advice will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, after saving the Trained Model, instead of running the Model on the Test Data, you want to use the Inference for Predicting on a Single Instance.

If my understanding is correct, Yes, it is possible. Please find the below code snippet for inference.

```
pip install -q requests

import requests

headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}

json_response = requests.post('http://localhost:8501/v1/models/fashion_model:predict', data=data, headers=headers)

predictions = json.loads(json_response.text)['predictions']

show(0, 'The model thought this was a {} (class {}), and it was actually a {} (class {})'.format(
  class_names[np.argmax(predictions[0])], test_labels[0], class_names[np.argmax(predictions[0])], test_labels[0]))
```

For more details, you can refer the link, https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/serving/rest_simple#make_rest_requests